# Kohana - display buffered views or custom view on shutdown

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

I am using [Kohana `View_Core`](https://github.com/ascseb/kohana/blob/master/system/classes/view.php) derivative for my views. I would like to display buffered views or custom view on shutdown e.g.

1. If there were some errors/exceptions during the runtime => display error page
2. If executed with no errors => display the buffered output

The `View`

```
class View
{

private $file = '';

private $data = array();

private static $global_data = array();

public static $view = '';

private function __construct($file = FALSE, array $data = array())
{
    if ($file !== FALSE)
    {
        $this->set_filename($file);
    }

    if (!empty($data))
    {
        $this->data = $data + $this->data;
    }
}

/**
 * Creates new view object and returns it.
 *
 * @param string filename
 * @param array variables
 * @return object View
*/
public static function factory($file = FALSE, array $data = array())
{
    return new View($file, $data);
}

/**
 * Captures the output that is generated when a view is included.
 * The view data will be extracted to make local variables. This method
 * is static to prevent object scope resolution.
 *
 * @param string filename
 * @param array variables
 * @return string
*/
public static function capture($view_filename, array $view_data)
{   
    extract($view_data, EXTR_SKIP);

    ob_start();

    try
    {
        require $view_filename;
    }
    catch (Exception $error)
    {
        $ob_handlers = ob_list_handlers();

        if (!empty($ob_handlers))
        { 
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        throw $error;
    }

    return ob_get_clean();
}

/**
* Load view file
*
* @param string filename
* @return boolean
* @return object View
*/
public function set_filename($file)
{
    if (strpos($file, APP_DIR) === FALSE)
    {
        $extension = strrpos($file, '.') === FALSE ? '.php' : '';

        $path = APP_DIR.DIR_SEP.'system'.DIR_SEP.'views'.DIR_SEP.$file.$extension;
    }
    else
    {
        $path = $file;
    }

    if (!file_exists($path))
    {
        Error::throw_throwable('Unable to find file '.$path);
    }

    $this->file = $path;

    return $this;
}

/**
* Sets a global variable, similar to the set() method.
*
* @param string variable name
* @param mixed variable value
* @return object View
*/
public static function set_global($key, $value = FALSE)
{
    self::$global_data[$key] = $value;
}

/**
* Assigns a variable by name. 
*
* @param string variable name or an array of variables
* @param mixed variable value
* @return object View
*/
public function set($key, $value = FALSE)
{
    if (is_array($key))
    {
        foreach ($key as $name => $value)
        {
            $this->data[$name] = $value;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}

/**
* Renders the view object to a string. 
*
* @throws exception
* @param string filename
* @return string
*/
public function render($file = FALSE)
{
    if ($file !== FALSE)
    {
        $this->set_filename($file);
    }

    if (empty($this->file))
    {
        Error::throw_throwable('Unable to find file '.$this->file);
    }

    $data = array_merge(View::$global_data, $this->data);

    return View::capture($this->file, $data);
}

public function __toString()
{
    try
    {
        $result = $this->render();

        return $result;
    }
    catch (Exception $error)
    {
        Error::throw_throwable($error);
    }
}

public function __set($key, $value)
{
    $this->set($key, $value);
}

public function __get($key)
{
    return isset($this->data[$key]) ? $this->data[$key] : FALSE;
}

}
```

Usage

```
$content = View::factory('main/Main')
            ->set('order', !empty($_SESSION['order']) ? $_SESSION['order'] : FALSE)
            ->set('order_success', $order_success)
            ->set('items', $items)
            ->set('weights', $weights)
            ->set('ammounts', $ammounts)
            ->set('prices', $prices)
            ->set('total_price', $total_price)
            ->set('validator', FALSE)
            ;

$template = $this->get_template();

echo $template->set('content', $content);
```

What the previous lines do is echo a content view inside of template view. And this should be also the result that my shutdown handler is echoing if necessary. Is there a nice/easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to show a custom error page when there is an error. What I typically do here is to extend `Kohana_Kohana_Exception` class (as `Kohana_Exception`) and override the `public static function handler` method.

This lets you put in some code that can check what the error is (HTTP_404_Exception or other) what the environment is (dev / production) and do whatever behavior you want.

In my case, something like this:

```
// If not production and not an HTTP exception
if ( ! ($e instanceof HTTP_Exception) && Kohana::$environment !== Kohana::PRODUCTION)
{
    // Use built in error handler to show stace trace for developers
    Kohana_Kohana_Exception::handler($e);
    // ... exit(1);
}

// Otherwise
$injected_routes = array(Route::get('error'));
echo Request::factory('error-uri', NULL, FALSE, $injected_routes)
                ->headers(Request::$initial->headers())
                ->execute()
                ->send_headers(TRUE)
                ->body();
```

Here you need another route called `error` that matches `error-uri` and goes to another error controller/action/view that you can use to render your custom error page.

---

For this to work you need to have errors enabled by passing `'errors' => TRUE` to your `Kohana::init` call in `bootstrap.php`.

Comment: The concept behind `View_Class` seems to be perfect - I left that intact. However, I wrote a wrapper for this - another static `View_Class` method that checks whether the error array is empty or not. But this is also worth to look at if you are using the Kohana Framework as a whole.

Comment: Checked it using Kohana. Works like a charm, will try to reproduce/rewrite to my own classes. :)